# ST_GEOMFROMTEXT generated by ora2pg fails

Tags: postgis, oracle-spatial

I have a set of polygons inside a oracle table which represent circles. I am tryining to import these into postgres 12 using ora2pg.
An insert statement is created that translates the polygon to

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (CIRCULARSTRING (421819.9016 5376304.3194, 421744.9016 5376229.3194, 421819.9016 5376154.3194, 421894.9016 5376229.3194, 421819.9016 5376304.3194))', 32632)
```

Unfortunately this crashes if I try to import it.
Yet If I write it to:

```
ST_BuildArea(ST_GeomFromText('CIRCULARSTRING (421819.9016 5376304.3194, 421744.9016 5376229.3194, 421819.9016 5376154.3194, 421894.9016 5376229.3194, 421819.9016 5376304.3194)', 32632))
```

The import works quite well. Is there an option to rewrite the insert statements with ora2pg to this ST_BuildArea approach by default so I don't need to manipulate the insert statements by hand?

Comment: On Linux (GNU/sed): `sed -i 's/POLYGON/CURVEDPOLYGON/g' <inserts.sql>` (alter accordingly for heterogeneous WKT strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ora2pg seems to generate non-standard WKT. POLYGON is a geometry that is made from straight segments. Same kind of geometry with curved segments is a CURVEPOLYGON.

Edit POLYGON into CURVEPOLYGON and PostGIS accepts the geometry.

```
select 
ST_GeomFromText('CURVEPOLYGON (CIRCULARSTRING (421819.9016 5376304.3194, 421744.9016 5376229.3194, 421819.9016 5376154.3194, 421894.9016 5376229.3194, 421819.9016 5376304.3194))', 32632)
```

I think that the forum for asking questions about ora2pg and for reporting bugs is the GitHub repository https://github.com/darold/ora2pg.

Comment: Yes, that is technically correct and it works. Unfortunately curevpoygon type is not supported in ArcGIS Pro. So I need the workaround using ST_BuildArea.

Comment: also: the table definition is causing problems as ora2pg creates the table using "POLYGON" geometry type but the inset statements trying to create "CURVEPOLYGON" geometry which are in contrast to the polygon definition.

Comment: There is a suggestion to use JSON as a workaround in the ESRI forum https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-sdk-questions/importfromwkt-curvepolygon-type/m-p/1076402#M6839. And it is true that CURVEPOLYON is not included in the OGC standards. It is just listed as a future extension https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=25355